# NDK javah fails : class file has wrong version 50.0, should be 49.0

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, javah

I have looked at the various posts regarding **javah** failing but I have not found anything with this error that I am getting:

```
error: cannot access com.acme.ndktest.Sample
bad class file: bin/classes/com/acme/ndktest/Sample.class
class file has wrong version 50.0, should be 49.0
Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
com.sun.tools.javac.util.Abort
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Check.completionError(Check.java:169)
    at com.sun.tools.javadoc.DocEnv.loadClass(DocEnv.java:149)
```

The closest information I could find on the Internet was this
http://yonghoon.wikidot.com/ndk#toc4

> Each new release of the JVM increments the version number of the class
>   file. The list below shows the class version numbers that I know
>       Java 6: Version 50.0
>       Java 5 (1.5): Version 49.0
>       Java 1.4.2: Version 48.0

I don't get it I am using 1.6, Eclipse is set to JDK compliance 1.6,
I am running javah from the /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/jdk1.6.0_31/bin/javah folder.

/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/jdk1.6.0_31/bin/javah -classpath bin/classes -jni com.acme.ndktest.Sample

I am not sure why it says it should be 49, when I am using 1.6.

Some more information
javac -version  -> javac 1.6.0_31
javap -v -classpath bin/classes com.acme.ndktest.Sample | grep version
minor version: 0, major version: 50

In /etc/alternatives most of the java items point to java-6-sun like java and javac
But javaws points java-6-openjdk-amd64

I am Running Eclipse 3.7
Also does Ant have anything to with building these headers

Comment: What does /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/jdk1.6.0_31/bin/javah -version output?  Are you sure the NDK supports Java 6?

Comment: javah version "1.6.0_31"

Comment: What is the output of `javac -version` (without full path attached)? It seems to me that the java toolchain is not consistent. To check which versions your class files are, you can run `javap -v -classpath bin/classes com.acme.ndktest.Sample | grep version`. On Linux you may want to check `/etc/alternatives` links.

Comment: javac -version  -> javac 1.6.0_31 |

javap -v -classpath bin/classes com.acme.ndktest.Sample | grep version

minor version: 0, major version: 50

In alternatives most of the java items point to java-6-sun like java and javac
But javaws points java-6-openjdk-amd64java-6-openjdk-amd64

I am Running Eclipse 3.7
Also does Ant have anything do to with building these headers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issues was that some packages had been installed into the 
 /usr/java/packages/lib/ext by another application.

These were being used by javac to see decide the maximum possible jdk version to use. 
So doing this would fail

```
javac SomeFile.java -target 1.6
```

Giving this error message **Javac version 1.6 not able to build for target 1.6**

When you ran it with verbose option
javac -verbose -version SomeFile.java

it would list all the files in the /usr/java/packages/lib/ext

After moving all the files out of  /usr/java/packages/lib/ext

It compiles fine.